# org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value [STRING] value by reflection for String

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many

Does the `@Embeddable` for `@ManyToMany` relations and additional columns, works with `String`?
I do not use `@Generated Value for @Id`
Because my Entity `ApplikationUser`

```
@Id
@Column(length = 128)
private String applikationUserId;
```

by business logic has always an `Id`

Here my code:

```
@EmbeddedId
private ApplikationUserPopupMessageId applikationUserPopupMessageId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@MapsId("applikationUserId")
private ApplikationUser applikationUser;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@MapsId("popupMessageId")
private PopupMessage popupMessage;

@Column(name = "gelesen")
private boolean gelesen = false;
```

```
@Embeddable
public class ApplikationUserPopupMessageId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "applikation_user_id")
    private String applikationUserId;

    @Column(name = "popup_message_id")
    private Long popupMessageId;
```

```
@Entity
@Table
public class PopupMessage {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(length = 128)
    private Long messageId;

    private String title;
    private String message;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "applikationUser",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<ApplikationUserPopupMessage> applikationUserPopupMessages = new ArrayList<>();
```

```
@Entity
public class ApplikationUser implements UserDetails {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5517804528054972083L;

    @Id
    @Column(length = 128)
    private String applikationUserId;

    @Column
    private String password;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idRole")
    private Role role;

    private boolean enabled = true;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "popupMessage",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<ApplikationUserPopupMessage> applikationUserPopupMessages = new ArrayList<>();
```

**EDIT - 23.11.2020**
Regards the lack of interest, its seems to be possible to us `@Embeddable` with `String`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instantiate applikationUserPopupMessageId:

```
@Entity
public class ApplikationUserPopupMessage {
  @EmbeddedId
  private ApplikationUserPopupMessageId applikationUserPopupMessageId = new ApplikationUserPopupMessageId();
}
```

That's [known issue](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/JBPAPP-6475?_sscc=t)

Answer (score 2):

Just put getters and setters for the according properties in your `@Embeddable`.

Comment: Thank you. But there are getters and setters for everything...

Comment: Did you double-check visibilities and naming?

Comment: Yes. They are autogenerated by IDE

Answer (score 2):

Does it help if you annotate your entity class with Access level to Field

```
@Entity(access = AccessType.FIELD)
```